# IN for many elements

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-division

I have tables:

Table Site

```
╔════╦═══════════════╗
║ ID ║     NAME      ║
╠════╬═══════════════╣
║  1 ║ stackoverflow ║
║  2 ║ google.com    ║
║  3 ║ yahoo.com     ║
║  4 ║ cnn.com       ║
╚════╩═══════════════╝
```

Table Widget

```
╔════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME    ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ polling    ║
║  2 ║ comments   ║
║  3 ║ newsletter ║
║  4 ║ mail       ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

Table SiteWidget

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ SITE_ID ║ WIDGET_ID ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║       1 ║         1 ║
║       1 ║         2 ║
║       2 ║         2 ║
║       2 ║         3 ║
║       4 ║         2 ║
║       3 ║         1 ║
║       3 ║         3 ║
║       1 ║         4 ║
║       3 ║         4 ║
║       4 ║         1 ║
║       4 ║         4 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

I would like get all sites with comments (2) and mail (4).

I try:

```
SELECT * FROM Site 
LEFT JOIN SiteWidget ON Site.id = SiteWidget.site_id 
WHERE SiteWidget.widget_id IN (2, 4)
```

but this return me stackoverflow (2, 4 - OK), google.com (2 - NOT OK - without 4), yahoo.com (4 - NOT OK, without 2) and cnn.com (2, 4 - OK). 
How can i get all sites with 2 and 4? Always together, not singly.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `c#`, `java` and `php` at the same time? Could you narrow down the programming language you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    Site a
        INNER JOIN SiteWidget b
            ON a.ID = b.Site_ID
        INNER JOIN Widget c
            ON b.Widget_ID = c.ID
WHERE   c.Name IN ('comments','mail')
GROUP   BY a.Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df9ad/1)

if uniqueness was not enforce on `widget_id` for every `site_id`, `DISTINCT` keyword is needed.

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    Site a
        INNER JOIN SiteWidget b
            ON a.ID = b.Site_ID
        INNER JOIN Widget c
            ON b.Widget_ID = c.ID
WHERE   c.Name IN ('comments','mail')
GROUP   BY a.Name
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c.Name) = 2
```

Other Link

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Using HAVING can often be suboptimal, since more rows might have to be examined than might otherwise be possible.

Comment: @PaulDixon what do you mean then?

Comment: I just mean that people should use HAVING after exploring the alternatives, for example joining the widget table twice.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it - use an extra join so that you can look for combinations of 2 widgets:

```
SELECT * FROM Site s
INNER JOIN SiteWidget w1 ON (s.id = w1.site_id)
INNER JOIN SiteWidget w2 ON (s.id = w2.site_id)
WHERE w1.widget_id=2 and w2.widget_id=4;
```

Comment: this is good when the OP is always searching for two values only. What if he wants to search for 3 or 4 values? You need to add another join right? and that I think the query is not flexible and requires another resource due to joins.

Comment: That's correct - each additional value needs a join. Only benchmarking would tell you if it consumes more resources than using HAVING, but it should exhibit good index usage. Not difficult to generate such a query programatically for multiple values either (and you could move the WHERE clauses into the JOIN clauses to make it even easier to generate)

Comment: Anyway I agree on what you said `:D`

Comment: @PaulDixon, for what it's worth, I ran such benchmarks in a similar situation some time ago, and you are correct - the formula *does* exhibit very good index usage (MySQL 5.5). I expect it does on most platforms. I too find it easier on the clipboard :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM Site
INNER JOIN SiteWidget SW1
    ON SW1.widget_id = 2 
    AND Site.id = SW1.site_id
INNER JOIN SiteWidget SW2
    ON SW2.widget_id = 4
    AND Site.id = SW2.site_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you want filter by widget name

```
SELECT
    S.id,
    S.name 
FROM Site S
    JOIN SiteWidget SW
        ON S.id = SW.site_id
    JOIN Widget W
        ON SW.widget_id = W.id
WHERE W.name IN ('comments', 'mail')
GROUP BY S.Id,S.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT W.name) = 2
```

or if you want to filter by widget id

```
SELECT
    S.id,
    S.name 
FROM Site S
    JOIN SiteWidget SW
        ON S.id = SW.site_id
WHERE SW.widget_id IN (2, 4)
GROUP BY S.Id,S.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SW.widget_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Got to join twice

```
SELECT * FROM Site 
inner JOIN SiteWidget m ON Site.id = m.site_id and m.widget_id = 4
inner Join SiteWidget c ON Site.id = c.site_id and c.widget_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df9ad/12) (Thanks @JW. for the fiddle tables & data)

```
select s.id, s.name
from site s join (
   select sw.site_id, count(w.id) cnt
   from SiteWidget sw join widget w on sw.widget_id = w.id 
   where w.id in (2,4) 
   group by sw.site_id
) T on s.id = T.site_id and T.cnt = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally, you would need two different JOINs:

```
SELECT * FROM Site
    JOIN SiteWidget AS mail     ON (Site.id = mail.site_id AND mail.widget_id = 4)
    JOIN SiteWidget AS comments ON (Site.id = comments.site_id AND comments.widget_id = 2);
```

If you are sure that the SiteWidget table has no duplicates, e.g. because (site_id, widget_id) is primary key as is usually done for MtM relations, then you can also use HAVING: this is MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT Site.* FROM Site
    JOIN SiteWidget ON (SiteWidget.site_id = Site.id AND widget_id IN (2,4))
    GROUP BY Site.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

since, due to uniqueness, the only possibility for a site to appear twice is to have both widgets. Some believe this to be an abuse of `GROUP BY`, and some SQLs (PostgreSQL, if I remember correctly) will require `Site`'s fields to appear in `GROUP BY` or an aggregate functions in `SELECT` even if they functionally depend from the group-by column `Site.id`.

I find the first formula to be clearer and safer, and, I expect, more or less as fast as the second.

This is both because the many-to-many join table is very small (and index-covered to boot), and because this kind of operation was standard from day one, and is one of the most optimized. For example, I expect checks for widget_id 2 and 4 to run in parallel with a single logical read of the SiteWidget table in the join buffer. Even if they didn't, they would likely be loaded in parallel with a single *physical* read, the other hitting a SQL cache or, at the very least, the IOSS cache.

You might also try this slight variation, which should be the faster:

```
SELECT Site.* FROM Site
    JOIN SiteWidget AS mail     ON (Site.id = mail.site_id AND mail.widget_id = 4)
    JOIN SiteWidget AS comments ON (mail.site_id = comments.site_id AND comments.widget_id = 2);
```

which ought to run the main JOIN against the smallest SiteWidget table, and come out with id lookups into Site. This is actually what is likely to get done *even if you word the query as in the first instance*.

The first formula is perhaps easier to extend by copying and pasting if you ever need to add, say, the `polling` widget.